# Issues with prompt and function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page  with two forms where a user is to input their email and password. Upon entering the information correctly, the user will click on the Submit button then see a prompt that asks if they are sure with proceeding, if the user types in "Yes", the data in the email/password fields will be cleared. If they answer "No" then the information will stay. The issue I am having is that any response will clear all fields, when only the response "Yes" should do that. I can't seem to figure this out even though it seems very simple. Keep in mine please I am still a novice to HTML/Javascript.

Code for "Submit" button:

```
<button onclick="Submit()">Submit</button>
```

Code for function that decides whether the information is to be cleared or not:
function Submit() {

```
var ques = window.prompt("Are you sure?");
      if ((ques = "Yes")) {
        form.style.display = "none";
      } else {
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you actually submitting a `<form>` - if so, are you preventing the default action of form submit?

Comment: I do have the <form> </form> tag in between the code for the submit button but the function is outside of the form tags and in between the script tags. I am still learning Javascript/HTML so I am unsure of how I could possibly be preventing the default action of form submit.

Comment: search for event preventDefault on MDN

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution to clear inputs of form

```html
<body style="height: 100%">
    <form id="form" name='name' style='width: 100%; height: 60%;'>
        <input type="email" name="email"/>
        <button onClick='Submit()'>Click me</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    function Submit() {
    var ques = window.prompt("Are you sure?");
        if (ques === "Yes") {
            var inputs =document.querySelectorAll('input');
            inputs.forEach(input =>  input.value = '');
        } else {
              alert("hai");
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

I would suggest confirm over prompt for better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `prompt()` it's bad UX even in a test environment.
- Submit event involves

  - The form sending data to a server
  - The data is from all values of fields that have names (except buttons and outputs).
  - If there's no instructions to get the server response a blank page is returned. In the example the page doesn't go blank becauase the response is handled in iframe.

After rereading question I'm still not sure if you know what a submit event does. I'll assume that you want to interupt the submit event and give the user a choice of having the fields cleared of data or keeping the data after a submit event. If I got it wrong I'm sure you can swap the parts in my example to get the opposite effect.

This example:

- posts to a live test server
- has an iframe to display server response
- has only a click handler registered on the form
- has normal buttons not submit types
- first button opens a modal
- second button is on the modal "Yes" to keeping the data

  - closes the modal
  - uses the `.submit()` method to submit form
- third button is on the modal "No" to keeping data

  - does the same as "Yes"
  - and it uses the `.reset()` method to clear the inputs

### Example

```js
const form = document.forms[0];
form.onclick = xModal;

function xModal(e) {
  const io = this.elements;
  const clk = e.target;
  if (clk.matches('.trg')) {
    io.modal.classList.toggle("show");
  }
  if (clk.matches('.yes')) {
    io.modal.classList.toggle("show");
    this.submit();
  }
  if (clk.matches('.no')) {
    io.modal.classList.toggle("show");
    this.submit();
    this.reset();
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

legend {
  background: white;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  width: 12rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>

  <label>E-mail: 
  <input name='email' type='email'> Password: 
  <input name='pass' type='password'>
  <button class='trg' type='button'>Send</button>
</label>
  <iframe src='about:blank' name='response'></iframe>

  <fieldset name='modal' class='modal'>
    <fieldset class='content'>
      <legend>Page Will Reload</legend>
      <p>Do you wish to preserve entered data?</p>
      <button class='yes' type='button'>Yes</button>
      <button class='no' type='button'>No</button>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a little HTML snippet where a button makes a form disapear. I also used return false with the onsubmit attribute to prevent page reload, which could've been your problem.

```html
<body style="height: 100%">
    <form onsubmit='return false' id="form" style='width: 100%; height: 60%; background-color: red;'>

        <button onClick='Submit()'>Click me</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function Submit() {

            document.getElementById("form").style.display="none"
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

```html
<body style="height: 100%">
    <form onsubmit='return false' id="form" style='width: 100%; height: 60%; background-color: red;'>

        <button onClick='Submit()'>Click me</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function Submit() {

            document.getElementById("form").style.display="none"
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

enter code here

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this did not work. I'm not sure if my explanation was poor but essentially, after hitting submit, a prompt is displayed, if the user types in "Yes" then the information in the email/password fields clears. But if the user types in anything other than "Yes", the information should stay and the prompt should disappear. The issue is that when typing in anything other than "Yes", the information in the email/password fields is still cleared when it should stay there